# Geolocation APIs - doubts about the usage of coordenates (new to programming)

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and I was trying to run a code with a weather and geolocation API.

I created a function getLocation(position) so that I can get the latitude and longitude to display inside the apiUrl, but I can't find out what is wrong! It shows on console that can't read "coords" of undefined. Could someone help me please? :)

```js
let apiKey = "6ae49199fbcb90f6780234a44e9b9db4";
let unit = "metric";

function getLocation(position) {
  let geo = new Array();
  let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  return geo = [latitude, longitude]
}

//let apiUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${apiKey}&units=${unit}`;

function getPosition() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the result you're seeing? Which line is in error? What is the expected result instead?

Comment: can you check if you are using in https or http? The `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` will work on only https....

Comment: @Technoh when i console.log(position.coords.latitude) inside the function getLocation(), for example, it shows the value normally! 
But when I create a return to display an array with the variables, it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Technoh the goal is to insert them into the appiUrl (that is commented above), would it be better  if I put the apiUrl inside the function and return it?

Comment: I don't see any console.log in your code, which leads me to believe that there are some things missing. Please don't remove portion of your work because you think they are not relevant. If possible, create a jsFiddle with your code. If not, add comments about what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The undefined value may indicate that the user did not agree to send the location data. Moreover, it is good to pass the error callback to getCurrentPosition. In this callback, you can examine the cause of the error. Your code can be simplified a bit.
I included two examples. The second one uses the arrow functions syntax.

Below I prepared a small example:

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <script>
        function onSuccessCallback(position) {
          let lastLocation=[position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
          document.getElementById("location").innerText=lastLocation;
        }

        function onErrorCallback(err){
          document.getElementById("location").innerText=err.message;
        }

        //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback);

        //example using arrow functions
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          d => {
            let lastLocation=[d.coords.latitude, d.coords.longitude];
            document.getElementById("location").innerText=lastLocation;
          }, err => {
          document.getElementById("location").innerText=err.message;
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1 id="location"></h1>>
    </body>
  </html>
```